# Prove that $p\mid a^2+b^2\,\Rightarrow\, p\equiv 1\pmod{\! 4}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let a prime number $p$ divide $a^2+b^2$ with some  $a,b \in \left\{ 1,2, \ldots , p-1 \right\}$ Prove that  $p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Is the converse true?

I know that $a^2+b^2\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and I don't know.

Comment: Do you know the Legendre symbol?

Comment: Look in this website there is a lot of such questions

Comment: Odd prime. Let $c$ be the modular inverse of $b$. Then $(ac)^2\equiv -(bc)^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. But you probably already know that the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541665/fermats-2-square-like-results-from-minkowski-lattice-proofs for a discussion of this question and related ones.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I've noticed you always create new variables to denote e.g. inverse of $a$ instead of denoting it by $a^{-1}$. Why?

Comment: @user31415: Maybe just often. Convenience of typing? Partly. Trying to minimize syntactic complexity? That too.  Or, arguably, no good reason.

Comment: typically the result is $p \equiv 1 \mod 4 \leftrightarrow p = a^2 + b^2$  but if you replace the right side with $p | a^2 + b^2 $ there could be some more examples.   The solutions seem to indicate not.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/788003/242)

Answer (score 3):

$1)$ $\ \,a^2\equiv -b^2\,\Leftrightarrow\, (a/b)^2\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\, (a/b)^4\equiv 1\pmod{\!p}$, so $\text{ord}_p (a/b)=4$.

Fermat's little (FLT) $(a/b)^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{\!p}$ implies $4\mid p-1$ (proof below).

**Theorem:** $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{\!p}\,\Rightarrow\, \text{ord}_p a\mid k$.

**Proof:** If not, then $\,k=m\left(\text{ord}_pa\right)+r\,$ with $\,0<r<\text{ord}_p a$

But then $a^k\equiv (a^{\text{ord}_pa})^m(a^r)\equiv 1^ma^r\equiv a^r\equiv 1\pmod {\!p}$ - contradiction.

$2)\ $ By contradiction: if $\, p\equiv 3\pmod{\! 4}$,$\,$ then $\, a^2\equiv -b^2\,\Rightarrow\, (a/b)^2\equiv -1\,\stackrel{(p-1)/2}\Rightarrow$

$ (a/b)^{p-1}\equiv \color{#00F}{(-1)^{(p-1)/2}}\equiv \color{#00F}{-1}\, $ mod $p\,$ contradicts FLT.

Comment: how interesting! if $\mathrm{ord}_p (ab^{-1}) = 4$ then it's as if $ab^{-1} = \sqrt{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose  $a^2$ + $b^2$ = Mp with p  ≡ 3 (mod4). We must have by the main theorem concerning a sum of two squares the exponent of p must be even. Therefore 
$a^2$ + $b^2$ = M$p^{2n}$. On the other hand the maximum possible for $a^2$ + $b^2$ is 2${(p-1)}^2$. Hence it is deduced that M = 1 and the equality is impossible by a well known result of Fermat.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p|a^2+b^2$ then $a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod p$ hence by using Fermat's little theorem we have
$$
1\equiv a^{p-1}\equiv (a^2)^{(p-1/2)}\equiv (-b^2)^{(p-1/2)}\equiv (-1)^{(p-1/2)}b^{p-1}\equiv (-1)^{(p-1/2)}\pmod p
$$
Which means that $p|1-(-1)^{(p-1/2)}$, so $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Comment: How do you get $p = 1 \pmod 4$ after $p \mid 1 - (-1)^{(p-1)/2}$?