# Prove existence of certain lattice points in an ellipse

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conic-sections, problem-solving, integer-lattices, sums-of-squares

Here is a question that has puzzled me for a long time. I have figured out how to do the question a and b(i).

> (a) An ellipse, F, is centred on the origin. There are two distinct
> points inside F with position vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, such that
> $\vec y = \vec x + \begin{pmatrix}2a\\ 2b\end{pmatrix}$, where a and b are integers.
> Explain why the point with position vector $-\vec x$ is inside F and
> show that the point with positive vector $\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ is also inside
> F.

For question (a), I used the property of symmetry and convexity of ellipse.

> (b) The diagram shows an ellipse E centred on the origin. Also shown
> are points with integer coordinates and $2\times 2$ squares. [enter
> image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEaQx.png) Consider E to be split into its
> intersections with the various $2\times2$ squares. In this particular
> case there are four such intersections and each of these parts can be
> translated into the region $0\leq x,y \leq 2$, as shown.[enter image
> description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6zRs.png) All the parts of this particular ellipse fit
> inside the $2\times 2$ square without overlapping and therefore, in
> this case, E has area less than 4.
>
> (i) Use part (a) to prove that any ellipse centred on the origin with
> area at least 4 has a point with integer coordinates, other than the
> origin, inside the ellipse.

For question b(i), we can transform vectors $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$ into the $2\times 2$ squares by a translation of $\begin{pmatrix}2\lfloor{x/2} \rfloor\\ 2\lfloor y/2 \rfloor\end{pmatrix}$. As the ellipse has an area larger than 4, there must exist some image points overlapping in the $2\times 2$ square. Hence, with (a), the difference between these 2 vectors $\begin{pmatrix}\lfloor{x_1/2} \rfloor-\lfloor{x_2/2} \rfloor\\ \lfloor y_1/2 \rfloor -\lfloor{y_2/2} \rfloor\end{pmatrix}$ must be a lattice point inside E.

> (ii) Let $p$ and $u$ be positive integers and let C be the circle
> centred on the origin and with radius $2\sqrt{\frac{p}{\pi}}$ .
> Explain why there is a point with coordinates $(mp-nu,n)$, where m and
> n are integers which are not both zero, inside C.
>
> (c) The positive integer $p$ and $u$ are such that $u^2+1$ is an
> integer multiple of $p$. Prove that there are integers $x$ and $y$
> such that $x^2+y^2=p$.

I can see that question b(ii) and c are trying to use some number theory idea such as gcd or Bezout's identity. However, I am stucked and do not know how to apply results from a and b(i).

If it is possible, please give me some hints to proceed on b(ii) or c. Thank you!

Comment: the number theory aspect is that with a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$  there are integers with $p = x^2 + y^2.$  Due to Fermat, many proofs, this one seems within Minkowski's Geometry of Numbers.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541665/fermats-2-square-like-results-from-minkowski-lattice-proofs

Comment: @WillJagy, it is very helpful!! Thank you!